# Store Meteor collection in internal storage

Tags: cordova, meteor

I'am working on a mobile app created with meteor.js, but i am facing some issues with storing data (e.g. json's). The problem is, that when the mobile device is connected with usb and on the same wifi, then after closing the app, the database is still there, while running the app alone the database gets cleared/is not available.

For Example I have a collection

```
Datas = new Mongo.Collection('datas');
```

And i can save and edit or load data from this database. But whenever i close my App, the database gets wiped. So what is the best approach to keep the data in the collection?Maybe internal storage?. Is this the right way or am i missing something?

Comment: ok thx, so basicallyi just make a Ground.Collection?

Comment: @ghybs so when i use this, i cant acces files in public folder correct? nvm, problem goes with crosswalk plugin

Comment: What are your requirements?